# Data fetch from database using sessions not working properly

Tags: php, html, mysql

Basically I have a piece of php code with all of it's lines working and what they do is fetch the database data from certain session, now, the problem is that all lines are working except for one and i can't seem to understand why.

I have restarted my pc (it often works xD) and i've also tried exiting and re-entering the session to refresh it.

So basically I have the following code:

```
<?php
        include "Login-System/db.php";
        session_start();
        $first_name = $_SESSION['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_SESSION['last_name'];
        $email = $_SESSION['email'];
        $active = $_SESSION['active'];
        $user_name = $_SESSION['user_name']; 
?>
```

The only line not working is this one:

```
$user_name = $_SESSION['user_name'];
```

I have the value in the data_base but I keep getting the notice of variable Undefined.

What I want it to do is basically to show the fetched info from database like the previous code lines but it's just not happening.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You say you want to fetch data from the database, but you show us code getting data from a session. Also the line `$user_name = $_SESSION['user_name'];` itself cannot generate a notice of _variable Undefined_. Could you clarify your question? Show the exact error, and indicate the exact line where it occurs. Also do a `print_r($_SESSION);` to check what is stored in the session.

Comment: Use print_r($_SESSION) so you can see what exactly you have in $_SESSION (maybe there is a misspell).
Small tip: always check if variable is set, that will help to avoid critical errors.
Short version: $user_name = isset($_SESSION['name']) ? $_SESSION['name'] : ""; - here you check if it exists, you can also check is it is not empty etc.

Comment: Okay tanks  I did the "print_r($_SESSION)" and i saw that the value I wanted to put in wasn't even in the session -_- ty I solved my problem

Comment: you need to share db.php code also to understand complete code structure.

Comment: I think they're right because the thing you need to do is $ _POST instead of $ _SESSION and make your query after